# To show all the coefficients $c_i, \ 1 \leq i \leq n-1$ lie in the maximal ideal $p \mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Consider the irreducible polynomial $h(t)=t^n+c_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\cdots +c_1t+p \in \mathbb{Z}_p[t]$. Consider the ring of $p$-adic integers and maximal ideal $p \mathbb{Z}_p$.

I want to show all the coefficients $c_i, \ 1 \leq i \leq n-1$ lie in the maximal ideal $p \mathbb{Z}_p$.

I am thinking about Hensel's lemma.

If possible let, one of the coefficients $c_i$, say $c_k$ doesn't belong to $p \mathbb{Z}_p$, then reduction mod $p$ produces $$\bar{h}(t)=t^n+c_kt^k=t^k(t^{n-k}+c_k),$$ as a factorisation. Hence by Hensel's lemma the lift $h(t)$ of $\bar h(t)$  is reducible, which is a contradiction.

Thus all the coefficients $c_i$ lie in $p \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Am I correct ?

Comment: By assumption, your $c_i$ don't even lie in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ - maybe you need to assume this? (If not start by clearing denominators).

Comment: @Mummytheturkey,  sorry it was typo. I corrected it

Comment: This doesn't seem true, consider $t^2+t+1$, so long as your field doesn't contain  a third root of unity it is irreducible yet contradicts what you're attempting to prove.

Comment: @Merosity, you can't consider the constant coefficient being $1$. I said it is a prime element $p$

Comment: Ah of course, I missed it.

Comment: @CalvinLin, which constant term ? $f(x) $ or $\bar f(x)$   ? The constant term of $f(x)$ is $p$ which is not zero because here $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integer not of characteristic $p$ but of characteristic $0$

Comment: @Why AH yes, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @CalvinLin,it is alright. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is ultimately correct, the only modification you need to make is that there could be arbitrarily many coefficients that aren't 0 mod p, in particular,

$$\bar h(t) = t^n + c_{i_1}t^{i_1} + \cdots + c_{i_k}t^{i_k} =  t^{i_k}(t^{n-i_k} + c_{i_1}t^{i_1-i_k} + \cdots + c_{i_k})$$

Your factorization will still lift by Hensel's lemma like you describe because they satisfy the condition that they are relatively prime polynomials.